# How to execute one build many times with different compiler flags in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to working with Jenkins and could use some help.

Right now, I have a project I want to build with Jenkins. I have a rough idea on how to build a simple project. What im wondering is, can I build the project with certain compiler flags, and then build the project again with different flags automatically?

My goal with all this is to be able to submit a program to Jenkins, and it will compile the program, run some tests, and then restart but this time with different compiler settings. Then I check the results to see under which compiler settings the code runs fastest.  I need to use Jenkins and I need to do this testing.

My current strategy was to setup a master/agent system, and have the Master server go through a pipeline where each step it compiles the code a certain way and pushes it to the appropriate agent queue where it will be executed. Is this feasible? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood you correctly but I will do the different build you want to run the same compile/tests with different flags.

I will do a jenkins pipeline with all together and I will start different stages sequentially like:
Stages:

- CheckSCM (git clone)
- Build with flag1
- cleanWS (CleanWork Space)
- CheckSCM
- build with flag2
- cleanWS
- CheckSCM
- build with flag3